# ¿Cómo cambiar el nombre de un correo enviado desde laravel con gmail y markdown?

Tags: php, laravel, gmail, markdown

Estoy usando gmail para enviar correos desde mi aplicación en laravel.
Los correos se envían de manera satisfactoria pero hay un detalle en el nombre.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Envio el correo usando este codigo en mi controlador:

```
Mail::to($resp_validacion['email'])->send(new Subscribe($resp_validacion['email'],$resp_validacion['name'],$resp_register_new_student['pass']));
```

Con esta clase:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class Subscribe extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $email;
    public $user;
    public $pass;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($email, $user, $pass)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Gracias por unirte a GPC')
        ->markdown('emails.subscribers');
    }
}
```

y en la vista:

```
@component('mail::message')
# Bienvenido a GPC

Querido {{$user}}

Ten enviamos este mensaje para que puedas acceder al sistemas GPC
Usuario -> {{$email}}<br>
Contraseña -> {{$pass}}

@component('mail::button', ['url' => 'url de prueba'])
Ingreso GPC
@endcomponent

Gracias,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

Estoy buscando por todo lado pero no encuentro como cambiar ese "Example" me gustaría poner otro texto o simplemente el nombre de la institución, necesito ayuda por favor para poder cambiar esa parte.
config/mail.php :

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Mailer
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default mailer that is used to send any email
    | messages sent by your application. Alternative mailers may be setup
    | and used as needed; however, this mailer will be used by default.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mailer Configurations
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure all of the mailers used by your application plus
    | their respective settings. Several examples have been configured for
    | you and you are free to add your own as your application requires.
    |
    | Laravel supports a variety of mail "transport" drivers to be used while
    | sending an e-mail. You will specify which one you are using for your
    | mailers below. You are free to add additional mailers as required.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "ses",
    |            "postmark", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: La mejor forma es cambiarlo en tu archivo `config/mail.php`, en la propiedad `'from'`, si no sabes cómo hacerlo, muéstranos qué tienes en tu archivo de configuración. [Revisa la doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#using-a-global-from-address) para más detalles.

Comment: 'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

Comment: eso aparece, pero en todo caso podría configurarlo de frente en el .env? o seria suficiente con ponerlo en el mail.php porque tengo el correo de origen en el .env MAIL_USERNAME=**********@gmail.com

Comment: Puedes configurarlo ahí mismo ya que estás, o definir una variable de entorno, lo que prefieras. Si lo haces ahí, sería poner más o menos: `'from' => [ 'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'tuNombre@tuDominio.com'), 'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Tu Nombre'), ]`

Comment: En cambio, si quieres hacerlo en `.env` define allí los valores que deseas para `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` y para `MAIL_FROM_NAME`.

Comment: subi el mail.php y no estoy seguro si usa ese from o llama los valores de 'mailers'

Comment: ¿Cómo que no estás seguro, ya viste, al recibir el correo, que está usando los valores que hay en el apartado ***Global "From" Address***,  cambia los valores ahí o define una variable de entorno directamente (no sé si en Laravel manejas un  archivo `.env` directamente), como prefieras. No veo por qué te complicas tanto.

Comment: mi duda era justo por eso, en laravel uso el .env y en mailers.smtp.username recupera el correo del cual me llega el mensaje, en cambio en el from aparece 'hello@example.com' y nunca use ese correo, estaba así por defecto y no lo modifiqué pero probaré y reenviaré el correo para ver que resulta, hasta pensé en ponerle un mailers.smtp.name o algo parecido

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano por tu apoyo, laravel tomó en cuenta el From pero en caso del correo usa el configurado en el env. el problema esta solucionado